# Updated file is not showing into artifact after successful completion of build pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline, artifact, build-pipeline

There are two updated files and they are successfully merged into the branch of repository but when i am trying to run the build pipeline , artifact is creating without any issue but the change is reflecting only to one file out of two updated files, there is no change seems to be appear into another one, in generated artifact.

I am not getting any leads to fix this issue, and I am expecting change in both of the files in generated Artifact.

**Edit:-**

Here is my the content of .gitignore file and I am changing the file which is present in the folder in the eighth line of the image . But I have also added a file in the folder which is on the seventh line, that file changes are visible but not the file which is in the folder of eighth line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with the following things to fix the issue:

1. Ensure the build is running for the right branch and commit that contain all the latest updated files. You can check the information on this **Summary** tab of the build.

   [image]
2. After successfully building the code, ensure you have used the [Copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) to copy all the required artifact files into the directory **`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`**.
3. Then use the [Publish Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-pipeline-artifact-v1?view=azure-pipelines) to publish the artifact files from the directory **`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`**.

---

**EDIT:**

In above step **`#1`**, you can click on the commit ID to open it in Azure Repos. Then check whether the updated files and updated contents are listed.

If the build is running for multiple commits, on the **Summary** tab, you can click "**`View xx changes`**" to all commits of current build. You can click and open the listed commits one by one to view the updated files and updated contents contained in them. And ensure the updates in newer commits do not override that in older commits.

[image]

In addition, ensure the checkout task in the build job has checked out the latest commit version which is listed on the **Changes** page. Normally, this latest version contains the latest updates (Added, Deleted, Modified) of each source file.

---

**EDIT2:**

On the **Summary** tab of the build, click on the commit that the build is running for. This commit should be the latest one among all changes that the build is running for. And the checkout task also should check it out to build by default.

Then follow the steps showing in the image below.

[image]

If the problematic file does not contain the updates as you expect on this commit. I am afraid that someone had modified the file to override the expected updates before this commit. You can open the commit history of this file to view who and when modified this file before.

---

Comment: Thank you so much for replying but as I mentioned above, two out of one file is showing change but the second file is not showing the change in the file in artifact and I have checked all your mentioned steps, all seems to be correct. Also I don't want to make any changes in build pipeline because for everything it is working fine except this one file.

Comment: @user14021668, I have updated my above answer with more suggestions. Check and try it.

Comment: Yes , Changes are listed there but not reflecting into the artifact.Actually the file in which I am expecting changes is added first time into the repository but after generating artifact that file is replacing it's content with the previous version of itself,which was already present there , not with the current version.Is there something to do with .gitignore?

Comment: @user14021668, Check with the steps mentioned under **EDIT2** in my above answer.

Comment: I have checked with your Edit2 steps, the file in which I am expecting change is looking perfect and the changes are visible there but not in the artifact one.

Comment: Is there something to do with  .gitignore file ??

Comment: I have added the snippet of .gitignore file above,  please check it if there is any issue @Bright Ran-MSFT

Comment: @user14021668, What is the path of the file under the project directory?

Comment: I have mentioned it above in edit section Please check it @Bright Ran-MSFT